# sqlalchemy : How does Base know that i have defined a class mapped to it?

Tags: sqlalchemy

It just works when I simply do an inheritance with my class

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = ’users’
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

And then i'm able to create the table using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`

My question is, how can sqlalchemy know that i have already defined User (inherited from Base) ?

Comment: Because one is able to iterate over all sub-classes of the class (in this case `Base`). In fact,  the answer is in the question asked just 2 days ago: [How to iterate through every class declaration, descended from a particular base class?][http://stackoverflow.com/a/8957113/99594]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each declarative base class maintains the registry of descended classes, which is filled when class definition is executed (in `__init__()` method of metaclass). But this registry is not actually used by `create_all()`. The `MetaData` instance (`Base.metadata`) is a part of SQLAlchemy core (not ORM) and is responsible for maintaining the registry of tables. `MetaData` instance remembers the table when it is created (and stored in `__table__` attribute of class) from the same `__init__()` method of declarative metaclass. You can get this list of tables through `Base.metadata.sorted_tables` property.

Answer (score 3):

When you inherited from any class it will give you chain to trace over all its sub classes. With the help of trick given in [How to iterate through every class declaration, descended from a particular base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956928/how-to-iterate-through-every-class-declaration-descended-from-a-particular-base/8957113#8957113) you will get all sub classes.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I have another question related to this: how is the attribute `__table__`  of user-defined class (which inherits from declarative Base) specifically made according to the content of that defined class?

Comment: I check the coding and found that they are set on the bases of the __tablename__ attribute. Yoc can check the codding in http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/build/third_party/sqlalchemy_0_7_1/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py and check the function `def _as_declarative`.